# Show Data Loading status while data loading instead of showing "No records found" with PrimeNg

Tags: primeng-datatable

I am showing tabular data from an angular 2 application with the help of PrimeNg.

When I click on the link to show the table, it shows "No records found" even though data is still loading on the table and eventually the data do show up in the table once data loading is complete.

I want to avoid showing "No records found" , instead would like to show "Data loading....." on the page while data is loading and then show the PrimeNg DataTable once the whole data loading is complete.

Some hints to achieve this goal is eagerly expected.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to [emptyMessage](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable) property to customize this label :

```
<p-dataTable [value]="cars" [responsive]="true">
    <p-column field="vin" header="Vin"></p-column>
    <p-column field="year" header="Year"></p-column>
    <ng-template pTemplate="emptymessage">
        Data loading...
    </ng-template>
</p-dataTable>
```

Comment: This is still happening me. First it shows the empty message and then the data is loaded.